# Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke UWP analog

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Which is an analogue of Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke (such as WPF) exists in UWP?`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
             //some code here
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    // Do your stuff here
});
```

This will run your code on the UI thread, change the `CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal` to your liking.

Answer (score -1):

Extend [Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6184382/lloyd)'s answer:

```
async void SomeVoid(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
   await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
        //Your code here
   });
}
```